# how to update text field using listbox

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

i have access 2007 and i want to update a text field [eng] using a list box [List191] which contains 3 values value1,value2,value3

i want when i click on this list and select one or two values i get this values as text separated with (,) in that text field

something like :

```
Private Sub List191_Click()
Form_tbltest.[eng].Value = Form_tbltest.[eng].Value &","& Form_tbltest.List191.value 
End Sub
```

this code is not working with me , any suggestions ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a multi-select list box, look at the Access help topics for *ListBox.ItemsSelected Property* and *ListBox.ItemData Property*.

In this example, I chose the list box's After Update event for the code.  I named my text box *txtEng*.  The code loops through the list box's `ItemsSelected` collection, and adds the `ItemData` value for each to a string variable, *strEng*.  After the loop, the leading comma is discarded when the length of that string is > 0.  Finally the string's value is assigned to the text box.

```vb
Private Sub List191_AfterUpdate()
    Dim strEng As String
    Dim varItem As Variant

    For Each varItem In Me.List191.ItemsSelected
        strEng = strEng & "," & Me.List191.ItemData(varItem)
    Next
    If Len(strEng) > 0 Then
        strEng = Mid(strEng, 2) ' discard leading comma
    End If
    Me.txtEng = strEng
End Sub
```