# Access Multi-Select Listbox, Items Selected String, Text not Integer

Tags: vba, string, ms-access, text, integer

I am currently working on an Access Database and I am trying to create a string of selected items in a multi-select listbox separated by commas (ex. Option 1, Option 3, Option 5). I have been able to get the program to create a list, but it is listing Integers (1,3,5) instead of the text I wrote as the primary key for the data I am using in the listbox. I have tried changing my commands as Variant instead of Integer, but it is still listing 0-based numbers.
Does anyone know a solution to this problem or a code that creates the string out of text instead of integers?
Thank You!

This is the code I have currently (OptionL is the name of my list box)

```
Function LbxItems() As String
'Returns a list of items in the listbox
Dim lbx As ListBox
Dim varItems As Variant
Dim varItem As Variant
Dim strReturn As String
strReturn = ""
Set lbx = Me!OptionL
varItems = lbx.ItemsSelected.Count
If varItems > 0 Then
    For varItem = 0 To varItems - 1
        If varItem = 0 Then
            strReturn = CStr(lbx.ItemsSelected(varItem))
        Else
            strReturn = strReturn & "," & 
            CStr(lbx.ItemsSelected(varItem))
        End If
    Next
End If
Set lbx = Nothing
LbxItems = strReturn
End Function
```

Comment: Lindsay, without your code, it is guess work ...

Comment: Now show your listbox RowSource SQL.

Comment: Property Sheet- Row Source is "SELECT [OptionT].[OptionID], [OptionT].[OptionName] FROM OptionT;"

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19353316/77335) for an example of how to fetch values from selected rows of a multi-select list box and concatenate them into a string variable.

Comment: Value of each selected row is the bound column, in this case OptionID. If you want a different return, reference column by its index. Your code is also missing line continuation character `& _`. But could just be on one line `strReturn = strReturn & "," & lbx.Column(1, varItem)`.

Comment: Another example http://allenbrowne.com/ser-50.html. Don't need a Count of items selected.

Answer (score 0):

`.ItemsSelected(<some number>)` does not give you what I think you're expecting. It does not give you the value from any column within that selected row.

Use [ItemData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.listbox.itemdata) if you want the value contained in the *Bound Column* of a selected row.  So you could make changes like this to your existing code:

```vb
'strReturn = CStr(lbx.ItemsSelected(varItem))
strReturn = CStr(lbx.ItemData(lbx.ItemsSelected(varItem)))
```

However I would switch to a simpler approach like this:

```vb
Public Function LbxItems() As String
    Dim strReturn As String
    Dim varItem As Variant

    With Me.OptionL
        For Each varItem In .ItemsSelected
            strReturn = strReturn & "," & .ItemData(varItem)
        Next
    End With
    If Len(strReturn) > 0 Then
        strReturn = Mid(strReturn, 2) ' discard leading comma
    End If
    LbxItems = strReturn
End Function
```

Comment: Okay. What all in my code should I delete and replace with that strReturn = line?

Comment: In other words what should the whole code look like

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the code from the link HansUp recommended to solve the problem. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19353316/77335) Thank you all so much!

Comment: This is typical text of a comment, not an answer. Please, put your comment in the right place and consider deleting this one.